# How can I change the tools on a bokeh plot created using mpl.to_bokeh?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bokeh

I am trying to display a complex signal in x and y and have the awesome interactive tools available from bokeh inside of an ipython notebook. In particular I would like to restrict the wheel zoom to the x axis, but I can't see how to do this after using `mpl.to_bokeh()`. Is there a way to set the default tools before using `mpl.to_bokeh()`?

For context here is a sample plot I would like to use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bokeh.plotting as blt
from bokeh import mpl
from bokeh.plotting import show
blt.output_notebook()
import numpy as np

blt.figure(tools='xwheel_zoom') # this doesn't help
x= np.arange(100)/100
y= np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*x)
ax= plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x,y.real)
plt.subplot(212, sharex=ax)
plt.plot(x,y.imag)
fig= mpl.to_bokeh(name='subplots')
```

Comment: This is no longer possible. Since Bokeh 12.5 (April 2017), [support for Matplotlib has been deprecated](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/4/5/release-0-12-5/), and `mpl.to_bokeh()` has been removed. Also see [this Github comment](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6249#issuecomment-299981362) by bryevdv.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, doing this with the MPL compat layer would already be somewhat difficult with just a single plot. I am not sure there is currently any way at all to do it with a grid plot and MPL. However, it is pretty trivial to do if you use the bokeh API directly. In case that is an option for you, and it is helpful:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, gridplot, show
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100)/100
y = np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*x)

p1 = figure(tools='xwheel_zoom')
p1.line(x,y.real)

p2 = figure(tools='xwheel_zoom')
p2.line(x,y.imag)

grid = gridplot([[p1, p2]])
show(grid)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know of a way to lock the x axes together as well?

Comment: Yes, you just need to share the ranges. So in the code above, add `p2 = figure(tools='xwheel_zoom', x_range=p1.x_range)` to have linked panning on the x axes